# Query only returns entities if their child isnt null

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have the following query:

```
  @Query("SELECT new de.hiqs.project.Project(project.id, project.name, project.isArchived, " +
          "project.customer.id, project.customer.name, project.customer.smallestTimeUnitEnabled, " +
          "project.customer.smallestTimeUnit, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.id, " +
          "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.performanceRecord, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.startDateHour," +
          "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.startDateMinute, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.endDateHour, " +
          "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.endDateMinute, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.pause ) " +
          "FROM Project project")
  List<Project> findAllInOneRequest();
```

So i have a query which returns all projects with chosen attributes to get everything in one request and avoid the N+1 problem. As you see, `Project` has a relation(foreign key) to `DefaultDailyEntrySettings`. The problem is that not every project has a `DefaultDailyEntrySettings` child(null in the database). So the query only returns the `projects` which have one. I would like it to return all `projects` and just initialize `defaultDailyEntrySettings` with null if it doesnt exist instead of not returning `projects` without a `defaultdailyEntrySettings`. Is there a way to do it?

Another option would be to give every `project` automatically a `defaultDailyEntrySettings` with null fields instead of the foreign key being null, but i couldnt figure out how to do it with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```
@Query("SELECT new de.hiqs.project.Project(project.id, project.name, project.isArchived, " +
      "project.customer.id, project.customer.name, project.customer.smallestTimeUnitEnabled, " +
      "project.customer.smallestTimeUnit, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.id, " +
      "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.performanceRecord, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.startDateHour," +
      "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.startDateMinute, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.endDateHour, " +
      "project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.endDateMinute, project.defaultDailyEntrySettings.pause ) " +
      "FROM Project project " +
      "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project.defaultDailyEntrySettings)" +
      "UNION ALL " + 
      "SELECT new de.hiqs.project.Project(project.id, project.name, project.isArchived, " +
      "project.customer.id, project.customer.name, project.customer.smallestTimeUnitEnabled, " +
      "project.customer.smallestTimeUnit, null, " +
      "null, null," +
      "null, null, " +
      "null, null ) " +
      "FROM Project project " +
      "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project.defaultDailyEntrySettings)")
List<Project> findAllInOneRequest();
```

Comment: This just does the same thing the query is already doing. It only returns the projects with a defaultDailyEntrySettings. But i would like it to return **all** projects. The behaviour should be a) If the project has a `defaultDailyEntrySettings` then it should return the project with the defaultDailyEntrySetting(like it already does) and b) if the project doesnt have a `defaultDailyEntrySettings` return the project and just ignore or use null for `defaultDailyEntrySettings`. The projects falling into case b) are currently just ignored and not returned at all.

Comment: Im not allowed to use null like that, always getting a nullpointer. `UNION` also doesnt exist in the version im using. I guess the only solution i can think of is to split it up in two queries. One to get all projects with defaultDailyEntrySettings. And another one to get projects without defaultDailyEntrySettings. Afterwards i can just combine both results.

Comment: I agree with two queries. Not 100% sure about JPQL but that's a common way for such thing in SQL development.